# epoch time for GMT

Tags: date, aix, timestamps, timezone

On **AIX**

`date -u` gives date and time in GMT format 
`date` gives date and time in local timezone 
`date +%s` gives local time in epoch time

Is there a way to get GMT time in epoch format?

In the AIX I'm using, there are only -n and -u options available (so I'm unable to use -f option).

My aim is to calculate Offset in hours between localtime and GMT. 
I can parse `$TZ environment variable` which can be tedious. Instead divide epoch time difference between two timezones by 60 should approximately give me the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that time zones will change offsets for daylight saving time, and for other anomalies.   If you calculate the offset between local and GMT, that is only valid for that particular point in time. At another point in time, it could very well have changed.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. It varies. For my requirement, it's considered to Ok

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "local time in epoch format", `date +%s` always prints the number of seconds since the epoch, namely since 1970-01-01 UTC.  It's the same number in all timezones.

However, with most `strftime(3)` implementations `date +%z` will print the numeric offset of the specified timezone:

```
$ TZ=Australia/Darwin date +%z
+0930
$ TZ=America/Toronto date +%z
-0400
```

This works with GNU `date`, and with BSD `date`.  I have no idea about AIX though.

Assuming it works, you can calculate the offset in seconds of any timezone.  With `bash`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
offset="$(TZ="$1" date +%z)"
sign=${offset:0:1}1
hours=${offset:1:2}
minutes=${offset:3:2}
if [ x"${hours:0:1}" = x0 ]; then hours="${hours:1}"; fi
if [ x"${minutes:0:1}" = x0 ]; then minutes="${minutes:1}"; fi
printf 'offset of TZ=%s: %d\n' "$1" $(( sign * 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes ))
```

Comment: [AIX date](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm?lang=en) doesn't do `%z`. It's a wonder that it does `%s` which is an annoying omission from POSIX.

Comment: As @Gilles mentioned, date +%z doesn't give information about offset. It just prints zone: TAIST, CEST, etc,.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to calculate the difference in hours between UTC/GMT and local time, just ask it this way:

```
UTC=$(date -u +%H)
LT=$(date +%H)
DIFF=$((UTC - LT))
```

taking care to note that the result may be negative depending on time of day and relative locations.

Comment: if absolute value is desired (and you have a newer ksh), then: DIFF=$((abs(UTC-LT))); otherwise, use: DIFF=$((UTC-LC)); DIFF=${DIFF#-}

Comment: That won't work for `TZ=Australia/Darwin`, which is `+0930` off from UTC. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your AIX has at least Perl 5.9, then you can use the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) core module  to obtain the timezone offset in seconds:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -le '$t=Time::Piece->new;print $t->tzoffset'
```

For a particular timezone, do:

TZ=Australia/Darwin perl -MTime::Piece -le '$t=Time::Piece->new;print $t->tzoffset'